# Process query string in gst-rtsp-server

Tags: c, inheritance, gstreamer, rtsp, gnome

I want to create rtsp server which works like certain ip camera.

RTSP query to camera looks:

```
DESCRIBE /axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&camera=1&resolution=640x480&fps=15
```

The documentation of gst-rtsp-streamer says:

> Usually the url will determine what kind of pipeline should be
>   created. You can for example use query parameters to configure certain
>   parts of the pipeline or select encoders and payloaders based on some
>   url pattern.

But I can't find any examples to parse query string and creating different pipelines. I only see the way with different paths.

There was similar [question](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/RTSP-query-parameters-td4665877.html), but I can't understand the answer.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution!!!

I create subclass of GstRTSPMediaFactory and override create_element method:

```
typedef struct TestRTSPMediaFactoryClass TestRTSPMediaFactoryClass;
typedef struct TestRTSPMediaFactory TestRTSPMediaFactory;

struct TestRTSPMediaFactoryClass
{
    GstRTSPMediaFactoryClass parent;
};

struct TestRTSPMediaFactory
{
     GstRTSPMediaFactory parent;
};


static GstElement * custom_create_element(GstRTSPMediaFactory      *factory, const GstRTSPUrl *url);


G_DEFINE_TYPE (TestRTSPMediaFactory, test_rtsp_media_factory, GST_TYPE_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY);

static void
test_rtsp_media_factory_class_init (TestRTSPMediaFactoryClass * test_klass)
{
   GstRTSPMediaFactoryClass *klass = (GstRTSPMediaFactoryClass *) (test_klass);
   klass->create_element = custom_create_element;
}

static void
test_rtsp_media_factory_init (TestRTSPMediaFactory * media)
{
}

static GstElement *
custom_create_element (GstRTSPMediaFactory * factory, const GstRTSPUrl  *url)
{
     /* you can see at query string: */
     printf("query is: %s\n", url->query);
     /* according to query create GstElement, for example: */
     GstElement *element;
     GError *error = NULL;

     element = gst_parse_launch ("( videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )",
                          &error);
     return element;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ...  
   GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory;
   factory = g_object_new(TEST_TYPE_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY, NULL);

   ...
   g_main_loop_run (loop);

   return 0;
}
```

I hope it'll help somebody to safe time! I use sources and examples/test-cgroups.c for it

Comment: For anyone coming here in the future. Just one little correction:
You need to also define the type using:
`#define TEST_TYPE_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY              (test_rtsp_media_factory_get_type ())`.

Also for a C++ application, you'll need to explicitly cast the returned pointer from `g_object_new()` to `GstRTSPMediaFactory*`